# Clean used packages in .NET solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-cleanup

I have a bunch of solutions (.NET Core - although probably not that relevant) that during time gathered tons of unnecessary usings, PackageReferences, etc.

Is there a way or some tooling to mass/automatic clean all these?

Furthermore, with PackageReferences I need a solution that analyzes deeper because I would like to eliminate direct references to packages that are indirectly referenced by other packages that I use. I would like to only keep the 'top' ones who in turn will reference and load the others.

Comment: You can use `Resharper`. Please see this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html

Comment: Another tool is CodeMaid: https://www.codemaid.net/

Comment: If you're using VS 16.0.x or later, you can go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced and select *Show “remove Unused References” command in Solution Explorer (experimental)*. Then a *Remove Unused References command* should show up in the right-click menu of a project name or dependencies node in Solution Explorer. That might not do everything you want, but worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

For removing unused usings etc I really recommend using the StyleCop Analyzer package https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/. Then create your own ruleset within Visual Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-create-a-custom-rule-set?view=vs-2019. You should see a StyleCop section which you need to include when creating your ruleset. In your ruleset you can decide which warnings will be listed/ignored.

You can then hover over a warning in a class and apply the suggested fix to that issue/the issue throughout the class/the issue throughout the project.

You can get Resharper also which will give you another set of rules to play with. Also there is a StyleCop jetbrains plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11619-stylecop-by-jetbrains/versions which you will need to run the StyleCop rules as part of the Resharper 'Code Cleanup' which can be run from a shortcut. You will also need to install the following Visual Studio Extension for StyleCop https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop to make StyleCop appear in the right click context menu when selecting files and projects